# Javascript how to get values out of ADODB recordset

Tags: javascript, adodb

I'm trying to query a database, put the resultset into a map, and then close the database connection. However, when I try to iterate over my map object, I get

```
Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record
```

This makes me think that my map is still somehow associated with the resultset. I come from a java background and am just learning javascript, and it's making my head hurt. Any help would be appreciated. (side note - I understand that generally you shouldn't query a database in client side javascript, so please keep the answers technical)

```
    objConnection.Open(strConn);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM  JobConfiguration";
rs.Open(strQuery, objConnection);

var map = new Map();

rs.MoveFirst();
while (!rs.EOF) {
    map.set(rs.Fields.Item("Name"), {
            name: rs.Fields("Name").value,
            config: rs.Fields("Configuration").value
        });

    var item = document.createElement('option');
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.Fields("Name").value));
    document.getElementById("jobList").appendChild(item);

    rs.movenext();
}

map.forEach(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
});
```